# Ajax success depending on response within response body

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a project and I figured out sideloading with ajax is the way to go, unfortunately I have more states then OK and Error.

The Situation is the following:

When I load the part of the page with ajax and the response site is empty, it's an OK and everything worked like it should.

However, when the response is tagged with warning I need to print it to the screen. Nothing too fancy I guess.

This is the code I'm working with:

For testing purpose I'd like to print everything that is in the response of my `/backend/posthourssingle` to an span with the ID `alert_saveinfo_{{ ma.persnr }}`. Working with Twig variable works, I have the span and the output is `"res:"` without the content from the `/backend/posthourssingle`. When inspecting the element with the network tool in e.g. Chrome, I'm able to see the response as a HTML text.

```
<script>
  $("#submit_{{ ma.persnr }}").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = $("#formtosubmit{{ ma.persnr }}").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      url:'/backend/posthourssingle',
      data: json,
      success:function(result) { 
        response = result;
        //document.getElementById('alert_saveinfo_{{ ma.persnr }}').innerHTML = '"res:' + response + '"';

        showToast('success', 'Datensatz wird gespeichert!', 'Daten von <b>{{ ma.vorname }} {{ ma.nachname }}</b> ({{ ma.persnr }}) wurden in der Datenbank gespeichert.');
        // showToast('warning', 'Warning Head!', 'Warning Text.');
      }
    })

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but this comment looks suspect: `//document.getElementById('alert_saveinfo_{{ ma.persnr }}').innerHTML = '"res:' + response + '"';
`

Comment: I try to fetch the reponse on success and get the text within the `/backend/posthourssingle` and want to write it somewhere. When Using the line you copied, it just outputs the `"res: "` without an actual response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need get HTML from server, you need to specify `dataType: 'html'`, not `json`. See [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation

> **dataType** (default: `Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`)
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server
>   ...
>   `"html"`: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'json'
      dataType: 'html',
      url:'/backend/posthourssingle',
      data: json,
      success:function(result) { 
        response = result;
        //document.getElementById('alert_saveinfo_{{ ma.persnr }}').innerHTML = '"res:' + response + '"';

        showToast('success', 'Datensatz wird gespeichert!', 'Daten von <b>{{ ma.vorname }} {{ ma.nachname }}</b> ({{ ma.persnr }}) wurden in der Datenbank gespeichert.');
        // showToast('warning', 'Warning Head!', 'Warning Text.');
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem! I'll mark as answered as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: Glad to help :)